# How do I Align Footer Links on my Word press site?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, footer, vertical-alignment

I'm working on wordpress site with a customize theme and i am trying to align the footer links on my website horizontally. I'm looking at the css style sheet for the footer and have the following code for the footer:

```
.lower {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 2.6875rem;
    padding: 0 4rem;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    align-items: center;    
    justify-content: center;
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: $off-white;
        text-transform: lowercase;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: $tablet_lg) {
        padding: 0 8rem 0 16rem;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }
    & > div {
        text-align: center;
        @media screen and (min-width: $tablet_lg) {
            text-align: left;
        }
```

How do I align it so that the social media links, page contact info and two images side/bside are all aligned vertically.

Comment: We're going to need to see some HTML, to get a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and I guess an additional screenshot doesn't hurt. We can't really help you debug from just the CSS.

Comment: From the scss how the footer was coded: